# Return pair of vector iterators from a const method

Tags: c++, class, vector

I try to return a pair of vector iterators from a `const` method.

```
pair<vector<double>::iterator, vector<double>::iterator> Matrix::GetColumn(int j) const {
  return pair<vector<double>::iterator, vector<double>::iterator>(values_.begin() + j * height_,
                                                                  values_.begin() + (j + 1) * height_);
}
```

I get the following error at compile time

```
matrix.cc:119:133: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> > >::pair(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const double*, std::vector<double> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const double*, std::vector<double> >)’
   return pair<vector<double>::iterator, vector<double>::iterator>(values_.begin() + j * height_, values_.begin() + (j + 1) * height_);
                                                                                                                                     ^
```

The iterators are pointers to the begin and the end of the `vector<double>`, allowing the user to edit values in the vector. AFAIK this does not come out of the scope of `const` does it ?

The class looks like this :

```
class Matrix {
    int height_;
    int width_;
    vector<double> values_;
}
```

When I remove `const` the error goes away.

Comment: The members are `const` in a `const` method, therefore `values_.begin()` returns a `const_iterator`, not an `iterator`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mch. One additional question : do const method always return const values ? I know this method is not supposed to alter `this`, but what about the callers ?

Comment: @matthiasbe No, but access to the members in such a function is `const`, and "const" vectors can't expose an `iterator`, only a `const_iterator`. So it's not a general rule, but you'll encounter this pattern a lot. It's indeed to protect the object not just from the function itself, but from the callers.

Comment: @mch Don't answer in comments please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A const function can't mutate the state of the class, so it can only return a const_iterator.

If it were to return a non-const iterator that would have the side effect of allowing the outer scope (calling code) to mutate the class's state. This would mean that the const function **allowed modification of the class's state**, even if it is indirectly (i.e not happening within the scope of that function).

This breaks the contract that the const keyword implies.